# Add words as label for word embedding

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard, word-embedding

I'm trying to visualize my word embedding with tensorboard, but can't solve problem with label.
The problem is, that I have variable like this:

```
word_embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size,word_embedding_size],-1.0,1.0))
```

and when I save it for next use in tensorboard:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver({"word_embeddings": word_embeddings})
embeddings_save_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder_name, 'name.ckpt')
save_embeddings = saver.save(sess, embeddings_save_path)
print('Model saved')
```

as label I see only index(1...vocabulary_size)

When I print word_embeddings variable I see only numbers ie:

```
[0.000 0.000 ...]
[0.000 0.000 ...]
[0.000 0.000 ...]
```

How do I add the label ie: 
`blue:  (0.01359, 0.00075997, 0.24608, ..., -0.2524, 1.0048, 0.06259)` (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/embedding )

I'm not very familiar with this area so if I don't add here all the necessary information let me know.

I do some search here but answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258391/tensorboard-embedding-example) was not very helpful